# WSO2 Identity Server 5.1 Alpha will not start, hangs

Tags: startup, alpha, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I got the 5.1 Alpha release today and was unable to get it to completely start.  it hangs at (or after) this log message:

```
INFO {org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule} -  TLD skipped. URI: http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles is already defined
```

I am starting it up with the same environment and command that I've been running. 5.0.0.  sh wso2server.sh
Here is my full log.

```
JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/
CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to /servers/wso2is-5.1.0-alpha
[2015-10-05 10:55:09,154]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Starting WSO2 Carbon...
[2015-10-05 10:55:09,155]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Operating System : Mac OS X 10.10.4, x86_64
[2015-10-05 10:55:09,155]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Home        : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
[2015-10-05 10:55:09,155]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Version     : 1.7.0_79
[2015-10-05 10:55:09,155]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java VM          : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 24.79-b02,Oracle Corporation
[2015-10-05 10:55:09,156]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Carbon Home      : /servers/wso2is-5.1.0-alpha
[2015-10-05 10:55:09,156]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Temp Dir    : /servers/wso2is-5.1.0-alpha/tmp
[2015-10-05 10:55:09,156]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  User             : jsimon, en-US, America/New_York
[2015-10-05 10:55:09,259]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.bootup.validator.util.ValidationResultPrinter} -  Carbon is configured to use the default keystore (wso2carbon.jks). To maximize security when deploying to a production environment, configure a new keystore with a unique password in the production server profile.
[2015-10-05 10:55:09,263]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.AgentHolder} -  Agent created !
[2015-10-05 10:55:09,279]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.internal.AgentDS} -  Successfully deployed Agent Client
[2015-10-05 10:55:09,405]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.identity.notification.mgt.NotificationMgtConfigBuilder} -  Secret Resolver is not present. Will not resolve encryptions in config file
[2015-10-05 10:55:09,486]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.ldap.server.configuration.LDAPConfigurationBuilder} -  KDC server is disabled.
[2015-10-05 10:55:12,869]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager} -  LDAP connection created successfully in read-write mode
[2015-10-05 10:55:13,180]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService} -  Configured Registry in 69ms
[2015-10-05 10:55:13,577]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent} -  Registry Mode    : READ-WRITE
[2015-10-05 10:55:14,068]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.UserStoreMgtDSComponent} -  Carbon UserStoreMgtDSComponent activated successfully.
[2015-10-05 10:55:14,524]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Starting WSO2 Carbon...
[2015-10-05 10:55:14,524]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Operating System : Mac OS X 10.10.4, x86_64
[2015-10-05 10:55:14,524]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Home        : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
[2015-10-05 10:55:14,524]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Version     : 1.7.0_79
[2015-10-05 10:55:14,524]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java VM          : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 24.79-b02,Oracle Corporation
[2015-10-05 10:55:14,524]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Carbon Home      : /servers/wso2is-5.1.0-alpha
[2015-10-05 10:55:14,524]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Temp Dir    : /servers/wso2is-5.1.0-alpha/tmp
[2015-10-05 10:55:14,524]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  User             : jsimon, en-US, America/New_York
[2015-10-05 10:55:18,768]  INFO {org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule} -  TLD skipped. URI: http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles is already defined
```

This is at the top of the log at DEBUG level:

```
JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/
CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to /Users/jsimon/Documents/servers/wso2is-5.1.0-alpha
[2015-10-07 07:29:22,411] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.context.internal.CarbonContextDataHolder} -  Started Setting up Authenticator Configuration
[2015-10-07 07:29:22,573] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.context.internal.CarbonContextDataHolder} -  Completed Setting up Authenticator Configuration
[2015-10-07 07:29:22,574] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.context.internal.CarbonContextDataHolder} -  Unload Tenant Task: org.wso2.carbon.context.internal.CarbonContextDataHolder$CarbonContextCleanupTask was registered.
[2015-10-07 07:29:22,574] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.context.internal.CarbonContextDataHolder} -  there can be a possibility of the same class loading twice and then trying to reset the initial context factory builder
java.lang.RuntimeException: A queue manager instance has already been set.
    at org.wso2.carbon.queuing.CarbonQueueManager.setInstance(CarbonQueueManager.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.context.internal.CarbonContextDataHolder.<clinit>(CarbonContextDataHolder.java:200)
    at org.wso2.carbon.context.CarbonContext.getThreadLocalCarbonContext(CarbonContext.java:123)
    at org.wso2.carbon.utils.logging.appenders.CarbonDailyRollingFileAppender$1.run(CarbonDailyRollingFileAppender.java:55)
    at org.wso2.carbon.utils.logging.appenders.CarbonDailyRollingFileAppender$1.run(CarbonDailyRollingFileAppender.java:53)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.wso2.carbon.utils.logging.appenders.CarbonDailyRollingFileAppender.subAppend(CarbonDailyRollingFileAppender.java:53)
    at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.append(WriterAppender.java:162)
    at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:251)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:66)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:206)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.log(Category.java:856)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.warn(Log4JLogger.java:197)
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.StAXDialectDetector.detectDialect(StAXDialectDetector.java:177)
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.StAXDialectDetector.getDialect(StAXDialectDetector.java:162)
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.StAXDialectDetector.getDialect(StAXDialectDetector.java:154)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.util.StAXUtils$7.run(StAXUtils.java:518)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.util.StAXUtils.newXMLInputFactory(StAXUtils.java:495)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.util.StAXUtils.getXMLInputFactory_perClassLoader(StAXUtils.java:566)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.util.StAXUtils.getXMLInputFactory(StAXUtils.java:172)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.util.StAXUtils.getXMLInputFactory(StAXUtils.java:137)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.util.StAXUtils.createXMLStreamReader(StAXUtils.java:224)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.util.StAXUtils.createXMLStreamReader(StAXUtils.java:218)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.<init>(StAXOMBuilder.java:170)
    at org.wso2.carbon.base.ServerConfiguration.init(ServerConfiguration.java:125)
    at org.wso2.carbon.base.ServerConfiguration.forceInit(ServerConfiguration.java:216)
    at org.wso2.carbon.base.internal.CarbonBaseActivator.initServerConfiguration(CarbonBaseActivator.java:68)
    at org.wso2.carbon.base.internal.CarbonBaseActivator.start(CarbonBaseActivator.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
```

Comment: Same issue with the earlier M6 release.

Answer (score 0):

Can be due to some jars being corrupted. Check the md5 of your zip distribution (md5:  f96f610d7549e0285766a314e375a9f0  ) and if it matches try extracting it again. For me it works on OS X 10.9 64-bit running jdk1.7.0_79

Comment: Thank you for the md5; I'll check that.  There weren't any MD5s or anything on https://github.com/wso2/product-is/releases where I got my release.

Comment: Other note, I did try building from source and the resulting build had that same issue.  I'm using OS X 10.10.4 with JDK 1.7.0_79.

Comment: yep, same md5 on my zip file.

Comment: to get a better idea, try enabling DEBUG or TRACE logs from repository/conf/log4j.properties for the whole org.wso2.carbon package tree.

Comment: I added the start of the log in DEBUG showing exception.  Is there any way to attach a file? It gets long too quick!  :)

Comment: use gist or a pastebin...  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15821/stack-overflow-etiquette-for-sharing-files-and-resources

Comment: seems like an osgi bundle loading issue. (the exception is not related to it).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with 5.1.0.. I tried with Java 8 and WSO2 starts up fine after that.

Answer (score -1):

You can download zip file of the WSO2 Identity Server 5.1.0 Alpha from[1].
Extract it and successfully started the server.

[1] https://github.com/wso2/product-is/releases